# What's the largest possible value for chemical and how fast it's reached?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

500liter box has bottle inside which is leaking chemical with the speed of 1 l/min. Air is sucked out of the box with the speed of 30l/min, new pure air is coming in with the same speed. Everything is well mixed here, and t=0 amount of chemical is 0.

Question is: What's the largest possible value for chemical and how fast it is happens?

I marked: y=y(t) be the amount of chemical with function of time.
Rin= 30l/min be the fresh air coming in.
Rout= 30l/min be air sucked out.
Cin= 0/500 Concentration of fresh air coming in.
Cout= y(t)/500 Concentration of fresh air going out.
V=500l be the volume.

1.Then for derivative dy/dt=Cin*Rin-Cout*Rout
2.separate this
3.integrate
4.solve for y

So I'm thinking should the leaking chemical be directly substracted from Rin making the Cin=1/500?

Or should the equation be dy/dt=(30l/min-y(t)30l/min)y+1l/min ??

THanks